# ¿Cómo excluir información en el formato condicional?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

tengo una duda sobre un formato condicional en las hojas de calculo de google.

Deseo que cuando se ingrese en una celda un campo que no exista en un rango se pinte de un color específico.

Hasta el momento tengo lo opuesto que cuando ingrese en una celda un campo que si exista en un rango se pinte de un color específico. A continuación lo que tengo con una fórmula personalizada:

```
=MATCH(A1:A10,B$1:B$5,0)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que necesitaría es que se pinten cuando no se encuentren los números en el intervalo `B1:B5`, me imagino que debería de ser algo opuesto a `MATCH`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto, de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo conseguí, si alguien necesita alguna vez saber como hacer esto, es de la siguiente manera:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5,A1:A10)=0
```

Y se la debe aplicar a las celdas `A1:A10` y queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Otra posibilidad:

```
=ISNA(MATCH(A1;B$1:B$5;0))
```

Puesto que `MATCH()` te retorna el valor encontrado, o bien el valor especial N/A cuando no lo encuentra, puedes testear mediante `ISNA()` si se ha dado el segundo caso. De este modo coloreará las que no producen resultado positivo para `MATCH()`.